# How to update data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this json data and i want find..if 'id' is available then update the record else not.

```
// Here is my json

{
    "service":
     [ {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please check your question again, I can't understand what you want here?

Comment: I want to update this json data in my table

Comment: What is the issue you are facing in getting "id" from JSON?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, first convert it to a hash,

```
result = {
    "service":
     [ {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    }]
}.to_hash
```

Then You can loop through and update using find_by_id and try method

```
result[:service].each do |s|
Model.find_by_id(s[:id]).try(:update_attributes, {name: s[:name]})
end
```

Note: Reason we used `find_by_id` is to prevent record not found exception, it will just return nil if there is no record found for a given id. And `try`method also just try to run and if any problem happens it won't throw any error.

Comment: When i am writing this code...it is giving Internal server error

// my update code

def update
    Result = params[:service].to_hash
    Result[:service].each do |s|
    Service.find_by_id(s[:id]).try(:update_attributes, {name: s[:name]})
  end

// url

http://localhost:4000/services/bulk_update

// routes

get 'services/bulk_update' => 'services#update'

Comment: // Json paramenter

{
    "service":
     [ {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "1",
        "description": "Allkindofworks",
        "price": "200"
    }]
}  

Now tell where i'm wrong

Comment: what's exact error, and can you post your code pls.

Comment: Please add me on skype i will show you error....my skype id : (pradeepchauhan_pc)

Comment: I posted my code...check first comment and second comment

Comment: services_controller.rb:38: dynamic constant assignment
    Result = params[:service].to_hash

Comment: // Code
def update
    Result = params[:service].to_hash
    Result[:service].each do |s|
    Service.find_by_id(s[:id]).try(:update_attributes, {name: s[:name]})
  end

Comment: ............................

Comment: try changing your Result to result

Comment: Hi, If you have your result as params, you don't need to convert it as hash again, just do params[:service].each do |s|
Model.find_by_id(s[:id]).try(:update_attributes, {name: s[:name]})
end

Comment: hi, finally i got 200 ok

Comment: Here is my code

def update
    begin
      params[:service].each_with_index do |s, i|
      service = Service.find_by_id(s[:id])
        if service
          service.update_attributes(params[:service][i])
        end
      end
    rescue 
      render :nothing => true, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => :ok
    end
  end
It is updating only name but i want to update all field...and explain concept of begib and rescue

Comment: Now i'm getting this error
"Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return" "

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're going to get some JSON data, and then you want to update the `id` field if you can find it otherwise leaving it alone. Just leverage `json` to convert your JSON into a `Hash` (I'm going to assume you get it as a string), change the field if you find it, then change it back to JSON again.

It'd look a little something like this:

```
require 'json'

my_json_string = '{...}'

parsed = JSON.parse(my_json_string)
parsed['services'].each do |element|
  if element.has_key?('id')
    # do something
  end
end

# Finally, convert back to JSON
my_json_string = parsed.to_json
```

Comment: Here it is my code

When i am writing this code...it is giving Internal server error 
// my update code 
def update Result = params[:service].to_hash Result[:service].each do |s| Service.find_by_id(s[:id]).try(:update_attributes, {name: s[:name]}) 
end 
// url localhost:4000/services/bulk_update 
// routes get 'services/bulk_update' => 'services#update'